# executing a regex on keypress?

Tags: javascript

I have a reg-ex that I would like to run on keypress. However, my code does not appear to work. Code is below.

```
var f1c = document.getElementsByClassName('f1t').value; 
var validator = new RegExp('^[0-9.]*$');
var runner = validator.test(f1c);

if (runner){alert("Working");}
```

How would I reorganize this syntax for it to work?

EDIT:
https://jsfiddle.net/7ddwsm3m/

Comment: so attach the event on key press of the element. Not sure how it would work when there is no keypress code there.

Comment: I do. If I remove `if (runner)`, the code works. I'm just wondering if there is anything wrong with my syntax that would stop this from running.

Comment: Again, you do not have any code that attaches an event. Your code just runs when the script is executed. We should see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener in your code where you attach the event to the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So have to listen for each keypress. Now you are only testing the initial value of the input

```
var f1c = document.getElementsByClassName('f1t'); 
var validator = new RegExp('^[0-9.]*$');

f1c.addEventListener("keyup", function(ev){
  var value = ev.target.value;
  var runner = validator.test(value);

  if (runner){alert("Working");}
})
```